# Dynamically changing value in a bokeh generated HTML table

Tags: python, html, bokeh

I want the `sin(x)` value to change as soon as I change the corresponding `x` value in the table. (Start `bokeh serve` in CMD before running this code)

```
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
import  math
curdoc().clear()
x=[i for i in range(10)]

def update_y(x):
      y=[]
      for i in x:
            y.append(round(math.sin(int(i)),2))
      return y

y=update_y(x)
data=dict(x=x,y=y)
source=ColumnDataSource(data)
columns = [ TableColumn(field='x',title="x"),TableColumn(field='y',title="sin(x)") ]
dadat= DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=600, height=400,editable=True)

def update(attr,new,old):
      print('1')
      y=update_y(old['x'])
      print('2')
      source.data=dict(x=x,y=y)
      print('3')

source.on_change('data',update)
curdoc().add_root(row(dadat))
ses=push_session(curdoc())
ses.show()
ses.loop_until_closed()
```

After running this code and changing value of `x`, it changes the value for a fraction of a second, reverts back and goes to an infinite loop.

I think its because of `source.on_change` as it may be triggered when the source value gets edited inside the `update` function. Is there any way out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `source` at first and then initialize it every time a change occurs so that it doesn't go into an infinite loop. 
here's the complete code: (Observe the `update_table() function` )

```
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn
curdoc().clear()
#replaced `sin(x)` with `x+2`
x=[i for i in range(10)]
def update_y(x):
      y=[]
      for i in x:
            y.append(int(i)+2)
      return y

def update_table(x):
      y=update_y(x)
      data=dict(x=x,y=y)
      source=ColumnDataSource(data)
      columns=[TableColumn(field='x',title='x'),TableColumn(field='y',title='y')]
      data_table=DataTable(source=source,columns=columns,width=500,height=500,editable=True)
      curdoc().clear()
      curdoc().add_root(row(data_table))
      source.on_change('data',update)
def update(attr,old,new):
      update_table(new['x'])

ses=push_session(curdoc())
update_table(x)  
ses.show()
ses.loop_until_closed()
```